# Fade in/out while resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following: [**http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/318/**](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/318/)

The issue is that it's not a smooth animation. How I wanted it to work was:

1. Center the icon to the middle of the screen before displaying it.
2. Fade it in, and while it's fading in, resize it to something slightly larger, while staying in the dead center of the screen.
3. Fade it out.

How can I fix the animation to be completely smooth and feel as if it's a "pulse".

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Click Me!</a>

<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-heart {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var center_width = $(window).width() / 2;
    var center_height = $(window).height() / 2;

    /* Set the icon to the center of the screen. */
    $('.fa-heart').css({ 'left': center_width, 'top': center_height });

    /* Fade the icon in, resize it, and fade it out. */
    $('.fa-heart').fadeIn();
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '60px' }, 300);
    $('.fa-heart').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: What browsers are you intending to support?

Comment: As many as possible I think is always the key.

Comment: No it's not, supporting all the possible browsers will leave you very limited on the stuff you can do and how much effort it will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/336/

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var center_width = $(window).width() / 2;
    var center_height = $(window).height() / 2;

    /* Set the icon to the center of the screen. */
    $('.fa-heart').css({ 'left' : center_width - 24, 'top': center_height - 24 });

    /* Fade the icon in, resize it, and fade it out. */
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '60px', opacity: 1, 'left' : center_width - 30, 'top': center_height - 30}, 250);
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '48px', opacity: 0, 'left' : center_width - 24, 'top': center_height - 24}, 250);
});
```

What I did is instead of using the fadeIn() and fadeOut() I used the animate() to change the size and opacity at the same time. You can change the times so they resemble a real heart beat but because both the size change and opacity change are in the same animate() they will happen at the same time. The third value in the animate() is to set the center of the picture to the center of the page. This needs to be center_height (or center_width) - 1/2 of the picture height so the center of the image is aligned with the center of the screen. You need the offset because in normal CSS the position tag aligns your picture with the specified value relative to the top left corner (0, 0 of the picture). The times of the animate can be changed depending on how fast / slow you want the heart to "beat".

Comment: Alright, that works. It still leaves one issue though. How do I resize the icon while its position stays in the dead center of the screen?

Comment: check the new one out. it sets the picture to the center - 1/2 the image size so the picture will be set at the center of the screen relative to the center of the icon, not the top left.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate CSS properties instead of using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`. And for centering the heart you need to:

```
(width/height) of the window     (width/height) of the heart
----------------------------  -  ---------------------------
              2                               2
```

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/337/)

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var w = ($(window).width() / 2) - ($('i').width() / 2);
    var h = ($(window).height() / 2) - ($('i').width() / 2);
    $('.fa-heart').css({ 'left': w, 'top': h });
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '48px', opacity: '0'}, 100);
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '60px', opacity: '1'}, 700);
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '48px', opacity: '0'}, 500);
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.fa-heart {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve a smooth and (arguable) faster animation using Julian Shapiro's [velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) plugin

just tweak your css giving `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none` to your element

```
.fa-heart {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
 /* display: none; */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

then velocity's `loop` option will give you the effect you want

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("body").on("click", ".click", function () {
        var center_width = $(window).width() / 2;
        var center_height = $(window).height() / 2;
        $('.fa-heart').css({
            left: center_width,
            top: center_height
        }).velocity({
            opacity: 1,
            fontSize: "60px"
        }, {
            loop: true, // animate from initial values back and forth
            duration: 400 // adjust as needed
        });
    });
});
```

... that way you don't need `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`, or animate back to the original values or chain several `animate()` methods

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nao9k1Lx/)**

**Notice** that you can set how many times you want the animation to take place by setting the *number* in the `loop` option like

```
loop: 1 // or twice, three times, etc (true does infinite loop)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nao9k1Lx/1/

Also notice I gave a *class* `click` to the `<a>` tag to be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

I've [updated your JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/330/), tell me if this is what you needed, i can explain the differences.

html

```
<a href="#">Click Me!</a>

<div class="anim-container">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var center_width = $(window).width() / 2;
    var center_height = $(window).height() / 2;

    /* Set the icon to the center of the screen. */

    /* Fade the icon in, resize it, and fade it out. */

    $('.fa-heart').fadeIn();
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '55px' }, {duration: 300, queue: false});
    $('.fa-heart').animate({ fontSize: '48px' }, 300);
    $('.fa-heart').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: as an added note, my answer shows the heart perfectly centered vertically and horizontally